# How to add custom (non const) string information to log format?

Tags: logging, go

I have started working with logging in Go and I have encountered this article about logging in Go https://www.goinggo.net/2013/11/using-log-package-in-go.html

with the following source code (slightly changed):

```
var (
  Trace   *log.Logger
  Info    *log.Logger
  Warning *log.Logger
  Error   *log.Logger
)

func Init(
    traceHandle io.Writer,
    infoHandle io.Writer,
    warningHandle io.Writer,
    errorHandle io.Writer) {

    Trace = log.New(traceHandle,
        “TRACE: “,
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    Info = log.New(infoHandle,
        “INFO: “,
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    Warning = log.New(warningHandle,
        “WARNING: “,
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    Error = log.New(errorHandle,
        “ERROR: “,
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
}

func main() {
  Init(ioutil.Discard, os.Stdout, os.Stdout, os.Stderr)
}
```

now I would like to add some custom information to log entries produced by this logger but which are not const string literals (like added there `INFO:` or `WARNING:`)

For example I would like to add a name of the function in which the log has been triggered. Let's say I have the following function which I would like to use for this: (from [here](http://sabhiram.com/go/2015/01/21/golang_trace_fns_part_1.html))

```
func _enter() {
  // Skip this function, and fetch the PC and file for its parent
  pc, _, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
  // Retrieve a Function object this functions parent
  functionObject := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
  // Regex to extract just the function name (and not the module path)
  extractFnName := regexp.MustCompile(`^.*\.(.*)$`)
  fnName := extractFnName.ReplaceAllString(functionObject.Name(), "$1")
  fmt.Printf("Entering %s\n", fnName)
}
```

How can I add this to the logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The simplest answer of course is to just type it in when you write the line of logging.  Lots of libraries actually use a convention like

  `logger.Logf("myfilename.go:123" + "other logging info")`

  where 123 is the line number. This is pretty scriptable by an ide or editor as well.
- If you change `_enter()` to return the name of the function, that would make the rest of this much simpler.  You can call `logger.SetPrefix()` inside each function, which might look like the following based on your example code.

  `Info.SetPrefix("INFO: " + _enter() + ":")`

  You could wrap the logger in a struct that would help do the above automatically, but you should be aware of the overhead of making the call to `_enter()` *every* time.
- Though at this point, you might want to look into using a logging library with more features.  I have had good experiences with [logrus](https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus) which can be a drop in replacement for the standard lib's log package.